# How to update many documents in MongoDB, from a list of documents?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have the following situation:

Documents to be saved:

```
[
    {
        character: "Elf",
        mana: 222
    },
    {
        character: "Human",
        mana: 100
    },
    {
        character: "Dwarf",
        mana: 0
    }
]
```

And I have in my mongodb the following:

```
[
    {
        character: "Elf",
        mana: 150
    },
    {
        character: "Human",
        mana: 50
    },
    {
        character: "Dwarf",
        mana: 50
    }
]
```

How is the best way to make an update so the characters get the proper values for their mana?

I cannot assume values to be more than a certain value, and may be I have another 50 more objects of different characters.

If I don't find the character in the database I want to insert the new character, otherwise just update it.

I have being looking in the documentation but looks like `updateMany` is not what I am looking for, and `update` one by one looks expensive.

How can I do this properly?

Comment: nvm, was reading it wrong.

Comment: Maybe multiple `update` and `insert` calls are so bad if you wrap them in a [`bulkWrite`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#bulkwrite-write-operations-executionofoperations) call

Comment: Are these character-objects individual documents in a collection or is it an array in one document containing multiple character sub-objects you are showing us here?

Comment: @k0pernikus I think you are right I will take a look into bulk operations, as making this update / insert one by one is kind of expensive. Thx for the adivce.

Comment: @Philipp is one collection called characters and we have an array of documents with those characters, and their updates.

Answer (score 4):

mongodb `update` can do multiple update but can not accept array to update. So you have to go one by one. If you want to do all parallel then use `async.each` like below.

```
async.each(docs, function(doc, next){
    db.collection('characters').update({character:doc.character},{$set:{mana:doc.mana}, $setOnInsert:{character:doc.character}},{upsert:true}, function(err, res){
        next(null, null);
    })
    }, function(err, res){
        // all data have been updated.
    })
```

Comment: We can also use bulk update. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.update/